# Remove IList<int> items from IList<int> items

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to remove `List<int>` items from `List<int>` items2

```
List<int> item1 = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
List<int> item2 = new List<int> {1,2,3,4};
```

After removing the item2 values from item1 the required result is

```
item1 = {5,6,7,8,9,10 }
```

Is there any direct method or any other method to remove the contents of one list of items from the content of another list of items, with out using 'for' or 'foreach' ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something *somewhere* is going to have to loop. You don't have to loop in *your* source code though. As to what you do... that depends on your requirements.

If you change the types of your variables to `List<int>` you could use `List<T>.RemoveAll`:

```
item1.RemoveAll(x => item2.Contains(x));
```

Or you could just use LINQ, if you're happy with `item1` changing value to refer to a different list:

```
item1 = item1.Except(item2).ToList();
```

Note that the above will *also* make `item1` a set of distinct values - if you have any duplicates, they will be removed (even if they're not in `item2`).

An alternative without the duplicate-removing aspect:

```
item1 = item1.Where(x => !item2.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Or to make it perform better if `item2` is large:

```
var item2Set = new HashSet<int>(item2);
item1 = item1.Where(x => !item2Set.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: +1. Jon Skeet never sleeps :). Nice very detailed answer as usual.